# Rails form_for additional field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need the user to enter a URL within my form. However, URL is not a column in my database. I get an error with the following form.

I have a form to create a video (new.html.haml)

```
= form_for @video do |f|
  .field
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
.field
  = f.label :description
  = f.text_area :description
.field
  = f.label :url
  = f.text_field :url
.field
  Provider
  %br
  = radio_button :video, :provider, 'vimeo'
  = f.label :provider, 'Vimeo', :value => 'vimeo'
  %br
  = radio_button :video, :provider, 'youtube' 
  = f.label :provider, 'Youtube', :value => 'youtube'
%br
.actions
  = f.submit "Add video"
```

Rails complains that URL is not a column in URL is an unknown method or variable.

**What I want to do**

Basically, I need to get an URL for the video the user is adding,along with the title of the video, its description and the provider.

All fields have a column in the databse, only URL doesn't.

I then need to format the URL and call some methods on it. It will create some new output that I will storin the databse.

So from URL, I get `provider_video_id`, `thumb` which are databse columns.

**How can I receive the user URL in my form without a dedicated database column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a virtual attribute.

Put in your model something like this:

```
def url=(url)
  @url = url
end

def url
  @url
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I actually used virtual attbutes in my controller following Ryan Bates'screencast, but I didnt know what to write in the getter and setter. I'll try your trick.

Comment: If that is exactly what you want to do, you may want to just add: **attr_accessor :url** in your model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag). It's not tied to any object, so it's what you want to use whenever you have a less-simplified reason for having a form. For instance, a search form would use a form_tag, and so would this case.

Comment: Thanks, for the moment I'll try nerian's answer, but i understand your solution and might use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to use Ruby class set/get, so Ruby has a magic for that.

This is an easy way to do

```
def url=(url)
  @url = url
end

def url
  @url
end
```

And this is a magical way to do

```
attr_accessor :url
```

With this line of code you will DRY your code.